# Splice temporary array will modify the main array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Is it normal that when I use splice on temp, mainArray is also modified ?

```
console.log(mainArray);

var temp = mainArray;

temp.airfares.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Given that they reference the same array? Yes.

Comment: That doesn't look like an array if it has an `.airfares` property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `temp` is not an entirely new array, just a reference to `mainArray`. You need to make a copy.

To easily make a copy of an array, using [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is common. Note that it will not copy each element, but will copy the array itself (so you can push or remove elements later).

For example:

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
document.getElementById("original").textContent = JSON.stringify(data);

var ref = data;
var copy = data.slice();

// Add some values to data, ref will change but copy won't
data.push(6, 7, 8);

document.getElementById("ref").textContent = JSON.stringify(ref);
document.getElementById("copy").textContent = JSON.stringify(copy);
```

```html
<pre id="original"></pre>
<pre id="ref"></pre>
<pre id="copy"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

`var temp = mainArray;` will set `temp` as a reference to `mainArray`.  That means, they both refer to the same array.  Therefore, if  you modify `temp`, you're also modifying `mainArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JavaScript arrays are objects, so `temp` and `mainArray` are both references to the same underlying object.

You want something along the lines of this:

```
console.log(mainArray);
var temp = mainArray.slice();
temp.airfares.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are stored as an reference not actual array is stored. An reference of it is stored (Since arrays are also object)

Here you can use `slice()` or `concat()` method's hack to assign it without reference

```
 var temp = mainArray.slice();
```

or

```
 var temp = [].concat(mainArray);
```